# weird text all over the plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

If I plot a pcolor plot without a colorbar I have no problem, but if I add the colorbar I get this strange output

```
figure(1); clf; pcolor(lineSeries); shading interp; colorbar
```

[image]

any idea why this happens?

lineseries has the dimensions

```
>  Name              Size                Bytes  Class     Attributes

>  lineSeries      691x1280            7075840  double
```

Comment: can anyone explain their down votes? What's wrong with the question? @Matthias Pospiech: Sorry can't help, same code produces a perfect result on my pc.

Comment: When trying to debug such issues it can be helpful to indicate your Matlab `version` and OS. Also, if your `lineSeries` is just `rand(691,1280)` do you still get the issue? Can you create a version with data that we can run here?

Comment: Your code looks like you activate a pre-existing figure window. Does the same problem occur if you make a new one? `figure` instead of `figure(1)`

Comment: The version is `8.0.0.783 (R2012b)`. The same happens with data generated with `rand(691,1280)` and if I use a new figure. Even if I restart Matlab, so that the history is empty and nothing is in the memory this happens.

Comment: Even with a newer Version (`8.2.0.701 (R2013b)`) the error stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use:

```
set(gcf, 'renderer', 'zbuffer')
```

As explained on http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/answers/53874